# How do I take information from several text boxes in PyQt5, and store them to their own individual class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to have access to the info in the text boxes in each individual class) so I can do calculations with the variables in each class I know how to do it without a GUI, but with a GUI like PyQt5

```
>>> a = 'ABC, DEF, GHIJ'
>>> a.split(',')
['ABC', ' DEF', ' GHIJ']
>>> a = a.split(',')
>>> c = '7.00, 8.00, 9.00'
>>> c = c.split(',')
>>> e = '7.20, 8.20, 9.20'
>>> e = e.split(',')


h = {}

class Profile:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.one = h['info1']
        self.two = h['info2']
        self.three = h['info3']


>>> e = []
>>> for i in range(len(a)): # Takes splitted info above, combines it, and adds it to a dictionary(Ex: h['info1'] = ABC, h['info2'] = 7.00, h['info'] = 7.20)
    h['info1'] = a[i]
    h['info2'] = c[i]
    h['info3'] = e[i]
    e.append(Profile(h['info1'], h['info2'], h['info3'])) # Adds each combined list index to its own individual class
```

Comment: Asking again the same question with the same code won't help you. If you don't know how to create a GUI based program, there are plenty of tutorials and how-to around the web. Sorry, but we won't tell you how to do it, because that's not how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

You would basically connect the signal of some widget, like `QPushButton.clicked` to a function that does the same thing as your original code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Profile:

    def __init__(self, h):
        self.one = h['info1']
        self.two = h['info2']
        self.three = h['info3']


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_boxes = [QLineEdit() for i in range(3)]
        form = QFormLayout(self)
        for i, v in enumerate(self.text_boxes):
            form.addRow(f'Box {i}', v)
        btn = QPushButton('Enter')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.get_values)
        form.addRow(btn)

    def get_values(self):
        a, c, e = [x.text().split(',') for x in self.text_boxes]
        h = {}
        profiles = []
        for i in range(len(a)):
            h['info1'] = a[i]
            h['info2'] = c[i]
            h['info3'] = e[i]
            profiles.append(Profile(h))

        print('Profiles saved', profiles)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```